# how to convert shape to volume?

Tags: mesh, bmesh, units

I have a 3d model (.stl) of building and I want to use it in other software.
The walls of the model are built with shapes, and I need the walls as volume.
There problem is that the model was made by shapes instead of volume.

How can I convert the shape to volume in blender now? any functions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You just have to fill the outer edges (the boundary edges loops) with other surfaces in order to achieve a confined volume. There is no such thing as "solids" in B3D mesh editing, only enclosed volumes.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, I guess it is because the volumes are not completely closed. I have added the new picture.

Comment: Suggest adding a link to stl or a blend file. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com